# didReceiveRemoteNotification method not calling in watch when getting push notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I am using push notification in ios and watch. Whenever I get push notification I would like to call one web service in watch.
I wrote the following method in `ExtensionDelegate.h` in watch.

```
- (void)didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo { 
    NSLog(@"notification fired");
   //Code for web service call
}
```

I didn't use dynamic notification interface and using static interface to  show notification. I tested push notification in device(watch). When I open my watch app via notification, `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method is not fired. I checked in xcode device logs by connecting my device.

How can I detect when push notification fired in watch?